# Login function always returns true

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having an issue getting a login function to work. It always returns true even though I enter the wrong credentials. Can anyone tell me why this is?

here is the function

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    global $pdo;

    $users = new Users;
    $user_id = $users->get_user_id($username);

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $query->bindValue(2, $password);
    $query->execute();

    if (!$query) {
        return false;
    }

    return $user_id;
}
```

and here is where it is implemented.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) === true) {
    header('Location: backend.php');
    exit();
} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields are required!';
    } else {
        $login = $users->login($username, $password);

        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Username or password incorrect!';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location: backend.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: You can use `$query->execute(array($username, $password))` instead of `$query->bindValue(1, $username);` & `$query->bindValue(2, $password);` & `$query->execute();`

Comment: Another side note: If you are using plain-text usernames and passwords, consider using [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) to generate salted hashes.

Comment: Storing cleartext passwords in db isn't the best thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Change your condition to,

```
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    return $user_id;
}
return false;
```

This verifies there is actually *a result* being returned by your query, not merely that the query exists.

Comment: that solved my problem but I do not understand why that worked, can you briefly explain y?

Comment: never mind it was because the query was always executing even though it did not return a result. Thanks

Comment: Because `$query` always be true if query execute properly without any error. But to check that you actually get a record or not you need to use `rowCount` :)

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation of PDO execute:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Id the query was succesful, it will return 'true'. This means that the query ran succesful, it doesn't say anything about how many results it returned. Depending on what you are trying to do, returning 0 results may be a succesful query.

Answer (score 0):

The select function always returns true.

Finding 0 rows is not considered a failure.

So this query:
    `$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");`  will always return true;

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this function is based on whatever 'phpacademy' course. For some reason it contains very strange part, makes code pretty entangled and bloated. It runs actually **two** queries against a database, which makes absolutely no sense.

What it have to be:

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    global $pdo;

    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?";
    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare();
    $stmt->execute(func_get_args());
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Application code is heavily bloated too. Why so much useless and repeated code? It takes much more time either to type and read.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: backend.php');
    exit();
} elseif ($_POST) {
    $login = $users->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    if ($login) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: backend.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Username or password incorrect!';
    }
}
```